# Migrating a project to a different computer: "Error: The device is not ready."

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, build

I'm using Visual C++ 2010 Express, and I just copied over a full project folder to a new computer (both are on Windows 8, if that's relevant). I opened the solution file exactly as I did on the other computer, and tried to build.

I'm getting the following error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: <project_name>, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Error: The device is not ready.
1>
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

With no other context.

What's the deal?

Comment: Hard disk error? Is it on a network disk? Is there a pre-build step?

Comment: The project is on Google Drive. Do you think that's relevant?

Comment: I took it off of Google Drive, and I've got the same problem.

Comment: So now it is on your local disk and outside the Google Drive folder, right? Can you build a new project in the same location?

Comment: No, I can't. Same exact issue as before.

Comment: well, the device is not ready

Comment: turn off/on might help

Comment: I have a feeling this error is a #error preprocessor message spit out by some code that is included as part of the project.

Comment: Well, I'm looking through the project now, and I can't find something like that...